# Prusa I3 MK2s with tilt in the X and Y directions

Tags: prusa-i3

So I converted my Prusa MK2S to use Duet electronics. I have always had problems with bed leveling. It doesn't appear to help much if any.

So I can complete a bed probing session but the result is never ever useable.

I think the problem I have is the bed is tiling in both the X and Y directions. I have gently crashed the Z-axis into the mount that holds the threaded rod and smooth rod. This is to ensure the X axis is parallel and not slopping to one side.

I have tried to manually level the bed using a metro link ticket. I think I have managed to get it close. However, I am unsure how to resolve the tilt in the Y direction.

If you're standing in front of the printer, it apppears to tilt towards your face. I have verified this using the metro link ticket. It feels closer at the back than towards the front.

What is the cause of this? How can I rectify this?